# Drawing vector diagrams

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question is:
Show that if $u$ and $v$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$, and v is non zero, that:
$$w = u - \frac{u · v}{||v||^2}v$$ is orthogonal to $v$.

This part was fine until I tried to draw a diagram. If $w = u - nv$ (since $(u · v)/||v||^2$ is a constant) is it not parallel to $v$?

Comment: Let just consider the dot product $w\cdot v$.

Comment: @SJane Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$w\cdot v= \left(u - \frac{u · v}{||v||^2}v\right)\cdot v=u\cdot v - \frac{u · v}{||v||^2}v\cdot v=u\cdot v-u\cdot v=0$$

For the diagram refer to the general scheeme for [Gram–Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) with $u=v_2$ and $w=u_2$

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I got this bit I was just wondering how a diagram of w, v, and u would look?

Comment: Just refer to the scheme here https://ccjou.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/orthogonalization1r.jpg with $w=y_2$ $v=y_1$ and $u=x_2$

Comment: The operation is that used for Gram–Schmidt process, indeed to obtain $w$ from $u$ orthogonal to $v$ we are subtrating to $u$ the projection of $u$ onto $v$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Answer (score 0):

Let us regroup the equation a bit:
$$
w = u - \frac{u \cdot v}{\lVert v \rVert^2} v
= u - \left( u \cdot \frac{v}{\lVert v \rVert} \right) \frac{v}{\lVert v \rVert}
= u - \underbrace{(u \cdot e_v) \, e_v}_{u_v}
$$

where $e_v$ is the unit vector in $v$-direction.

[image: scene]

This $w$ is $u$ minus that part of $u$, which points into direction of $v$,
so what is left over is orthogonal to $v$:

\begin{align}
w \cdot v 
&= \left( u - (u \cdot e_v) \, e_v \right) \cdot v \\
&= u \cdot v - (u \cdot e_v) (e_v \cdot v) \\
&= u \cdot v - (\lVert u \rVert e_u \cdot e_v)(e_v \cdot \lVert v \rVert e_v) \\
&= u \cdot v - \lVert u \rVert \lVert v \rVert (e_u \cdot e_v) \\
&= 0
\end{align}

You will see this decomposition again for the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalisation method.